# `MessageBox`, `SaveFileDialog` in .NET: which version should I use?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

Which one should I use and what are the differences:

[`System.Windows.MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox.aspx)

[`System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx)

The same question about [`System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) and [`Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog.aspx).

All I need is to show a message box and save file dialog (working on Windows XP as well).

Proper re-tagging is appreciated.

Thanks in advance, kh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The controls in the System.Windows.Forms namespace are for WinForms applications. The controls in the System.Windows namespace are for WPF/Silverlight applications. So pick the controls that match your application type.

Comment: +1 This is correct. And even though `Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog` is not in the `System.Windows` namespace, it is the save file dialog for WPF applications.

Answer (score 2):

One is from WPF the other one is the classic windows messagebox.

System.Windows is the WPF namespace
System.WIndows.Forms is the Win32 classic one.

In my windows forms application I would use the System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.

The same story goes for the SaveDialog